# Android Autocomplete textview multilines

Tags: android

I want to show 2 lines in autocomplete textview suggestion list. I have customer information such as customerid, customername and address. I want to show customername in first line and customer address in 2nd line. Is it possible to show multilines in Autocomplete textview?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done.  Just define your layout in a Linear or Relative Layout, and reference the fields individually.  Here's a link to a question about making two lines display, you can make the layout for the autocomplete as complicated as you like.

[Android: Make AutoCompleteTextView dropdown wrap to 2 lines or more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291182/android-2-line-autocompletetextview-dropdown/7880441#7880441)

Comment: It's a long time ago. I solved a issue and thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user553710 How it works here is either you delete your question, or you leave it for fellow developers who might encounter the same problem you had (1514 views) and give the answer to whoever found it.

You could've answered your own question too

Comment: @user553710 It would be great if you could describe the solution you used. Kindly add it as an answer.