# How to force AutoCompleteTextView drop down elements to wrap text in three or more lines?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm not able to force AutoCompleteTextView drop down elements to wrap text in three or more lines.

As you can see:

[image: drop-down before selection]

[image: drop-down after selection]

The text in the first image (drop-down element) disappears, but I wont it to wrap into more lines.

Edited: This is my xml code for the dropdown item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/dropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:lines="4"
    android:minLines="4"
    android:textSize="10sp"/>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have u tried changing the minLines attribute ?

Comment: set the android:layout_height ="wrap_content"

Comment: @Mehul1000 I tried to set the android:layout_height ="wrap_content" but it's not working... sill only one line

Comment: The better answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291182/android-2-line-autocompletetextview-dropdown/7880441#7880441

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!
My layout dropdown_multiline_item.xml code become:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="3"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The secret was on the two methods (into the adapter):

```
[...]

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    final String text = convertToString(cursor);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textContainer)).setText(text);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dropdown_multiline_item, parent, false);
    return view;
}

[...]
```

Hope this will help someone

Answer (score 0):

Define a TextView as an XML layout with all the properties you need to make it look right (lines, ellipsize, maxLines, minLines, etc). The use the [android:completionHintView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#attr_android%3acompletionHintView) attribute to set the dropdown to show the textview you defined.