# AutoCompleteTextView stops listening to onItemClick

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

**Existing code and xml**
The code

```
fromAutoComplete = new AutoComplete(
        this, R.layout.fromautocomplete,
        R.id.fromautocomplete);
fromAutoComplete.setNotifyOnChange(true);
fromAddress = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.fromAddress);
fromAddress.setAdapter(fromAutoComplete);
fromAddress.setOnItemClickListener(this);
fromAddress.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
fromAddress.setOnClickListener(this);
```

The xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fromautocomplete"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:minLines="2"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="sample text, a lot of text to encourage wrap text"/>
```

I need the autocomplete to wrap text, on the listview. So I add a LinearLayout around my autocomplete. This works. The listview on the autocomplete now has wrapped text. **but on selection non of my call backs are not called**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/fromautocomplete"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:minLines="2"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="sample text, a lot of text to encourage wrap text"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working,

Fixes

1. Gave a `id` to my `LinearLayout`
2. Used the layout `id` in my `onItemClick`
3. Used `R.layout.<file>` in the constructor

XML (R.layout.fromautocomplete)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toautocompleteLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toautocomplete"
```

Code

```
fromAutoComplete = new AutoComplete(this,
         R.layout.fromautocomplete,
                R.id.fromautocomplete);
        fromAutoComplete.setNotifyOnChange(true);
```

OnItemClick

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.fromautocompleteLayout) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get Textview from LinearLayout

```
@Override
public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                View v = (TextView)((LinearLayout )view).getChildAt(0);
                String s = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
               //Do something with string s
}
```