# Can I setup my an Android drop-down list layout to wrap lengthy items?

Tags: android, dropdown, word-wrap, autocompletetextview

**Problem - Trying to do:** I've been unsuccessfully trying to get lengthy items in a drop down list to wrap. I really wasn't sure it is possible. I have a drop down list with question options, which can be long in a few cases.

**What I have tried:** I've created a custom `TextView` layout for the adapter used to populate the `AutoCompleteTextView`. I've tried the usual and combinations of `wrap-content`, `android:singleLine=false`, `android:lines="2"` without any success. I really thought someone has probably tried this before

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:minHeight="25dp"
          android:padding="5dp"
          android:singleLine="false"
          style="@style/MyDropDownTheme"
          android:id="@+id/text1" android:hint="@string/hint_type">
</TextView>
```

**ArrayAdapter**

```
    ArrayAdapter questions = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.custom_drowdown_list_wrap, orgQuestions);
    question.setAdapter(questions);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291182/android-2-line-autocompletetextview-dropdown/7880441#7880441

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you would need a custom `Spinner` and it's `Adapter`. Something like this will help you.

```
class DynamicSizeSpinner : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner {

    var inOnMeasure = false
        private set

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        inOnMeasure = true
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        inOnMeasure = false
    }
}
```

```
class SpinnerArrayAdapter(context: Context, @LayoutRes layout: Int, val entries: Map<String, String>) : ArrayAdapter<String>(context, layout, entries.keys.toList()) {

    override fun isEnabled(position: Int): Boolean {
        return position != 0
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val selectedItemPosition = when (parent) {
            is AdapterView<*> -> parent.selectedItemPosition
            is DynamicSizeSpinner -> parent.selectedItemPosition
            else -> position
        }
        return makeLayout(selectedItemPosition, convertView, parent, R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item_custom)
    }

    override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        return makeLayout(position, convertView, parent, R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item_custom)
    }

    private fun makeLayout(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup, layout: Int): View {
        val tv = convertView ?: LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout, parent, false)
        if (position != -1) {
            (tv as? TextView)?.text = entries.keys.toList()[position]
        }
        return tv
    }
}
```

I'm using `Map` for the entries you can use a `List` or an `Array`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time with this great example.

Comment: @svstackoverflow did it help?

Comment: @ OhhhThatVarun - Yes. Since I'm still learning Android, I like to recreate it so I'm sure to understand it - particularly as java. I have a class to create all the spinners and drop downs, so I need to incorporate it into that if possible.